# 12864 LCD image not centered?

Tags: lcd-screen

Just flashed my Ender 5 Plus with the TH3D firmware so I could add an 12864... started a print and then a few minutes later I notice this on the LCD!

How would I fix this?

[image: fubar lcd]

Comment: Does it change when you peel off the plastic film?

Comment: Don't know- but it didn't change when I held my soldering gun to its head and threatened it... I'm guessing its a problem with the firmware, as opposed to it being mad about its film not being removed –

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with these cheap controllers with the timing.

With reference to the next reported issues:

https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/5703
https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/5720

Add these 3 lines after the `#define ENDER5_PLUS` in the firmware files:

```
#define ST7920_DELAY_1 DELAY_NS(250)
#define ST7920_DELAY_2 DELAY_NS(250)
#define ST7920_DELAY_3 DELAY_NS(250)
```